# Object#public_methods does not work as expected

Tags: ruby

I create a new module:

```
module M
  def self.g
  end
end
```

I would like to list all (class-)methods defined in `M`. Of course, `M.public_methods` would also list methods from `Object`, so I tried:

```
M.public_methods(false)
```

but when I try this in irb, it still lists a number of additional methods:

```
M.public_methods(false)
# => [:g, :freeze, :===, :==, :<=>, :<, :<=, :>, :>=, :to_s, :inspect, :included_modules, …]
```

I can get the result I want using

```
M.public_methods(false) - Object.public_methods
```

which surprises me. Shouldn't the `false` parameter already get rid of all the `Object` methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Shouldn't the `false` parameter already get rid of all the `Object` methods?

The wording of the documentation of [`Object#public_methods`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-public_methods) could certainly be improved. What is *meant* is that when the `all` argument is `false`, it only returns instance methods from the singleton class and the class of the receiver, but not any superclasses. So, in your case, the methods that are returned are the ones from `M`'s singleton class (`g`) plus all the public instance methods of `Module`.

You can verify this by comparing the output of `M.public_methods(false)` and `Module.public_instance_methods(false)`:

```
M.public_methods(false) - Module.public_instance_methods(false)
# => [:g]

M.public_methods(false) & Module.public_instance_methods(false) == 
  Module.public_instance_methods(false)
# => true
```

[`Object#singleton_methods`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-singleton_methods) will give you the answer you want:

```
M.singleton_methods(false)
# => [:g]
```